# google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound: 404 The project does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore database

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I am trying to use `google cloud datastore emulator` for testing some datastore code.

```
class GoogleDBHandler:

    def __init__(self, datastore_client, kind):

        self.client = datastore_client
        self.kind = kind

    def get_tables(self):
        # [START kind_run_query]
        query = self.client.query(kind='__kind__')
        query.keys_only()

        kinds = [entity.key.name for entity in query.fetch()]
        # [END kind_run_query]

        return kinds

 # starting testing google cloud datastore
    gc_datastore_client = datastore.Client()

    gc_datastore_handler = GoogleDBHandler(gc_datastore_client, kind='vendor')

    tab = gc_datastore_handler.get_tables()[0]
```

I got the following error,

```
google.cloud.exceptions.NotFound: 404 The project project_name does not exist or it does not contain an active Cloud Datastore database.
```

I have run the following commands before the testing,

```
gcloud beta auth application-default login

gcloud beta emulators datastore start
```

I am wondering what is the issue here.

PS. it is interesting that when I ran the data emulator and testing some code for the first time, it worked without any issue.

UPDATE

The issue has been solved as the `App Engine` was switched off, and it must always be on when using the `datastore emulator`.

Comment: Even though you are running application default login command try to pass the project ID and into the datastore.Client(''Project-id') method and check again.

Comment: @BravinBalasubramaniam it is the same as I passed the default `project-id`.

Comment: @daiyue you should add an answer with the solution (and accept it), not edit the answer in the question

Comment: Also - please describe in the answer how/where was App Engine turned off - IMHO it's a useful piece of info in the context.